# Rotation of Spherical Signals

Tags: group-theory, rotations

Let $x ∈ S^2$ be an arbitrary point on the unit sphere. In addition, let $L_R$ be the rotation operator taking a function $f$ and generating a rotated function $L_Rf$ by $[L_Rf](x) = f(R^{−1}x)$, where $R ∈SO(3)$.

I want to show that $L_{R^{−1}}$ is adjoint to $L_R$.

I have tried the following:

$[L_{R^{-1}}L_Rf](x)=[L_{R^{-1}}f(R^{-1}x)](x) = f(RR^{-1}x) = f(x)$

And therefore $L_{R^{−1}}$ is adjoint to $L_R$

Am I missing something? Is it  realy straightforward?